# jQuery, json, drop down oh my

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select, coldfusion

I have a form where if the user changes the platform (operating system), an ajax call is called and the available models are retrieved in json format.  I can get the ajax call to fire and I'm getting the data back formatted correctly but I can't get the model drop down to update with the new value (json value pairs).  I do not have ID's because some of the rows are dynamically added so I need to reply on traversing the DOM with items such as .next(), .find(), etc, and I'm not very good with this yet.

Here is the form:

```
<div class="field inline">
<label class="frmFlds_labels">Platform</label>
<select name="platform" onChange="updateModels(this,18);" class="platform">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="IBM" selected="selected">AIX</option>
    <option value="HP">HP-UX</option>
    <option value="LINUX">Linux</option>
    <option value="SUN">Solaris</option>
    <option value="WINTEL">Wintel</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="field inline" platform="IBM">
<label class="frmFlds_labels">Model</label>
<select name="model" class="model">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="LPAR on p550">LPAR on p550</option>
    <option value="LPAR on p561">LPAR on p561</option>
    <option value="LPAR on p570">LPAR on p570</option>
</select>
```

Here is the JS Code:

```
function updateModels(i,id){
var pltfrm = $(i).val();
var firstOption = $(this);
$.getJSON("index.cfm?do=misc.getModels&platform=" + pltfrm,
    function(j){
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++){
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
        }
        firstOption.next().children('.model').html(options);
    });
}
```

Comment: If the problem is on the client, show the client code, not your server code.

Comment: where is the event handler of this function?

Comment: I posted the server code so that you can see the format of the code in helping me using .next() or .find() or what ever.  There is no data delivery issue (for a change) LOL  The server code will help understand how the code is laid out on the page.  The code I posted is looped over 1 - 100 times.  I need help identifying the very "next" drop down option so that I can populate it.  I found an example of some code in a blog that was doing this but he was using table rows whereas I'm using DIV tags.

Comment: @AndreaTurri onChange='updateModels(this);'   It is in the passthrough of the CF custom tag.

Comment: @dlackey You should use .live() to do what you need, but you need to bind it in a different way I think.

Comment: Here is an example of some json data being returned: `[{"optionValue":"", "optionDisplay":"Select a model"},{"optionValue":"TBD", "optionDisplay":"TBD"},{"optionValue":"SCCM", "optionDisplay":"SCCM-standalone"}]
`

Comment: Let's take a step back for a second.  If the drop down value for "platform" is changed, how do I identify the next drop down using jQuery?  I believe the line `firstOption.next().children('.model').html(options);` needs to be rewritten.

Comment: You have a `#` in the name attribute of your element which is invalid: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

Comment: # is a coldfusion variable.  It's okay to be there.

Comment: @dlackey - I was wondering that as I do not know cold fusion well - you probably need to show the rendered markup to get the best jQuery answers here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I updated post with generated source code to make things simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you change your layout just a bit removing the code from the markup:
I added a custom attribute: `data-id`

```
<div class="field inline">
   <label class="frmFlds_labels">Platform</label>
   <select name="platform" data-id="18" class="platform">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="IBM" selected="selected">AIX</option>
     <option value="HP">HP-UX</option>
     <option value="LINUX">Linux</option>
     <option value="SUN">Solaris</option>
     <option value="WINTEL">Wintel</option>
     <option value="Other">Other</option>
 </select> 
</div> 
<div class="field inline" platform="IBM">
 <label class="frmFlds_labels">Model</label>
 <select name="model" class="model">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="LPAR on p550">LPAR on p550</option>
     <option value="LPAR on p561">LPAR on p561</option>
     <option value="LPAR on p570">LPAR on p570</option>
 </select> 
</div>
```

then use this:

```
function updateModels(p, id) {
    var firstOption = $(p);
    var pltfrm = firstOption.val();
    var model = firstOption.parent().next().find('.model');
    $.getJSON("index.cfm?do=misc.getModels&platform=" + pltfrm, function(j) {
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
        }
        model.html(options);
    });
}
$('.platform').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    updateModels($(this), id);// I do not see you using the id but...
});
```

EDIT: Different code if things get added dynamically to the page:

```
$(document).on('change','.platform', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    updateModels($(this), id);// I do not see you using the id but...
});
```

Comment: I do not have ID's because some of the rows are dynamically added.  Let me work with what you posted here and I'll see if I can tweak it.

Comment: `'data-id'` is simply a custom attribute but could be anything like 'data-cow'

Comment: I took your `var model = firstOption.parent().next().find('.model');` and your `model.html(options);` and it worked perfectly from there.  The ajax calls and json data were being returned, I just need to display that data and your solutions worked.  Thanks for sticking it out with me.  Why do you have to go to the parent() first?  Why can' t you just go to next().find()?

Comment: the change is on the 'select' and next (sibling) but to go the the NEXT DIV you get .parent().next() - the parents next sibling.

Comment: OOOOOOOohhhhhhh... because a DIV is a container.  So, I move up to the parent container!  I think it is starting to click.  Thank you!

Comment: Just to point out something perhaps NOT obvious in WHY I did the custom attribute:  `var id = $(this).data('id');`
also accesses the custom attribute `data-id` as data. `var myid = $(this).data('cow');` would set the value if I had set an attribute of: `data-cow='browncow'`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the traverse is from change handler on select and firstOption is the select, you need to go up to parent() and then next()

```
firstOption.parent().next().children('.model').html(options);
```

Comment: I see you added more code and it is scoped inside a function..."this" has no context and is undefined

Comment: "this" is supposed to reference the item changed.  Did I implement this incorrectly?

Comment: need to see more of your handler code, not sure what your arguments "i" and "id" are and "this" has no scope within the function